# Caught exception inaccessible after routing

Tags: jboss, exception, apache-camel

I'm building an exception handler for a jboss/camel project. Catching the exception with an `onException` clause works, and I can access the caught exception from a bean, but that work's only directly in exception handler. Since I need this handler in multiple different projects, I want to direct from the handler to a different route (in a different context), and handle the exception there centrally. But after the routing, the caught exception is not accessible any longer. Why is this, and how can I fix that. I'd like not to have to add another EJB to all of my projects.

#### Code:

```
<camelContext id="project1Context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <onException>
        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
        <handled>
            <constant>true</constant>
        </handled>
        <bean ref="projectSpecificBean" method="peekException" />
        <to uri="activemq:queue:centralExceptionHandling" />
    </onException>

    [... the routes of the context, where the exception happens ...]
</camelContext>
```

In the bean:

```
public void peekException(Exchange camelExchange) {
    Exception e = camelExchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
    log.warn("Caught general Exception", e);
}
```

This gives me access to the Exception inside the bean. But when I remove the `<bean ref="projectSpecificBean" method="peekException" />` from the `onException` clause and add the same thing to the route at `activemq:queue:centralExceptionHandling` (to a bean local to that project there, in a different camelContext), I cannot find the exception anywhere in the exchange.

Comment: Exceptions are not propagated to JMS queues. See the JMS page for what it sends to a JMS queue (according to the JMS spec)

Comment: @ClausIbsen Thanks - though that does not help solving the problem. And I just learned that `org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange` is not serializable, so calling an EJB that takes the `Exchange` as an argument to get that Exception wont work either. I start getting the feeling central exception handling isn't something camel really helps me to do...

Comment: You can use **vm** queue instead **activemq** queue. VM сomponent has no such restrictions as JMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to receive exception on the client of ActiveMQ queue you need use camel jms component option "transferExchange". This option must be enabled on both sides (during sending to ActiveMQ queue and receiving from it). In that case not only message body/headers will be sent but whole exchange will be transfered. See http://camel.apache.org/jms.html (transferExchange option). In general it will then looks like there are no queue between exception route and exception handler route. Here are some details from documentation:

> You can transfer the exchange over the wire instead of just the body and headers. The following fields are transferred: In body, Out body, Fault body, In headers, Out headers, Fault headers, exchange properties, exchange exception. This requires that the objects are serializable. Camel will exclude any non-serializable objects and log it at WARN level. You must enable this option on both the producer and consumer side, so Camel knows the payloads is an Exchange and not a regular payload.

Example of code:

```
<camelContext id="project1Context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<onException>
    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
    <handled>
        <constant>true</constant>
    </handled>
    <bean ref="projectSpecificBean" method="peekException" />
    <to uri="activemq:queue:centralExceptionHandling?transferExchange=true" />
</onException>

[... the routes of the context, where the exception happens ...]
</camelContext>

// Somewhere in the central exception handler.
<camelContext id="exceptionHandlerContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:centralExceptionHandling?transferExchange=true" />
    <!-- Here you will have almost completely the same exchange as it was before it was sent to ActiveMq -->
</route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: If the Exception will not serializable, you will receive an error when you try to put a message in the queue. But, maybe it depends on parameters of activemq

Comment: Please look my answer in details and also link to camel jms component:
**The following fields are transferred: In body, Out body, Fault body, In headers, Out headers, Fault headers, exchange properties, exchange exception. This requires that the objects are serializable. Camel will exclude any non-serializable objects and log it at WARN level.**

Comment: thanks, that did work! There is also the `transferException` option, which might have helped me, but having the whole Exchange is better for my case.